# How to programatically create a full user profile in windows?

Tags: windows, profile

I am trying to create a user profile for an existing user under windows. I am using the WinApi function CreateProfile to create the profile, but the profile created is very sparse. It only has a size of about 3Mb's. I have also tried using LoadUserProfile which unfortunately doesn't seem to do any better.

For comparison when you actually log the user in interactively the resulting profile has roughly 80Mb's on my computer.

So my question is: Does anyone know how to programatically create the full profile you get when performing an interactive first logon.

Comment: Do you know the user's password (or can you reset it)? Certain parts of the process may require the user to authenticate over the network so won't be possible without it. Also, why do you need to do this? Some of the "profile" is actually application settings/AppData which is created when each application first runs, e.g. internet temporary files, preferences etc. Why do you need to create these?

Comment: I don't believe that there is any realistic way to do this.  The first logon process is just too complicated to reproduce.  (Incidentally, 80MB is unusually high, though this is probably just due to some third-party software you have installed.)